# How to write a custom extension?

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, best-practice, development

Because I had a lot of issues lately with free and commercial extension I've decided to ask this question and answer it with the steps I usually follow when writing an extension. Feel free to edit the answer or add a new one.
In most of the cases when installing an extension or a theme I have to spend a few hours (sometimes more, sometimes less) to make it work on all the environments I need:

- dev: usually `localhost` where the project is in a subfolder
- preprod & live

This has happened even with extensions from large extension providers (that should remain nameless at least until I get really really mad and add their names in here)
**So the main question is..what steps should I consider when writing an extension to ensure the quality of the code and make it easier for a technical and non-technical person to use it and for a technical person to change it?**

Comment: It seems that one of the large extension providers didn't like this question and downvoted it. :)

Comment: Personally, absolutly no prob with Wyomind, but they encrypt their code and are still "premium partners" :( (just for example)

Comment: Hello Marius I need magento custom code development reference so can you provide me any resource for that?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Here is what I usually do:

1. **Always develop with `error_reporting` on.**
2. **Always develop with `isDeveloperMode` set to `true`. Just add `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1` to your `httpd.conf` file (or corresponding file for Nginx or something else)**
3. If the extension is linked to a core functionality add the
   dependency in the declaration file `<depends><Mage_Catalog /></depend>`
4. If the module is for community use, use `community` as codepool to
   give the developers the chance to override some classes without
   modifying the code directly
5. Put your frontend design files in `app/design/frontend/base/default`
   to make them available for all themes.
6. Put your admin design files in
   `app/design/adminhtml/default/default` and do not change the admin
   theme. I may want to change it in one of my modules.
7. Prefix your layout file names and template folder name with the
   company name to make it easier to isolate them.
   `easylife_articles.xml` and `app/design/.../easylife_articles`
8. Put your static resources (JavaScript, CSS, and images) in a similar folder as
   the template files `easylife_articles/images/doh.png`
9. Attach a simple text file with how to uninstall the extension: What
   files need to be removed, what tables need to be dropped, what
   config settings need to be removed from `core_config_data` table.
10. Do not write queries directly in models, blocks or helpers, use a
     resource model for that.
11. Do not write queries using the table names directly `Select * from
     sales_flat_order where ...`. Use a `Zend_Select` and transform the
     table names using `->getTable('sales/order')`.
12. Use the base url to include `js` files in template. **Wrong**
     `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/some.js"></script>`.
     **Right** `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'some.js'?>"></script>`
13. Do not rewrite classes unless is necessary. Use observers and if
     it's not possible to use helper methods that receive as parameter and
     instance of a class that you wanted to override. **Wrong**:
     Override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` to add the method
     `getProductArticles()`. **Right**. In your helper add
     `getProductArticles(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)`
14. If you override classes put a list of them in a `readme.txt` file
15. Use the default admin path for the admin section of your module.
     **Wrong admin URL** `articles/adminhtml_articles/index`. **Right admin URL** `admin/articles/index`
16. Add ACL for your admin sections. I may want to restrict access to
     some of the administrators.
17. Do not add another JavaScript framework (jQuery, MooTools, etc.) if it's not
     necessary. Write you code in the prototype.
18. Make you template HTML W3C valid (this is for OCD developers like myself).
19. Do not put images in the `media` folder. Use `skin`. The `media`
     folder usually is not versioned and this makes it harder to move the
     website to different environments.
20. Test your extension with flat catalog on and off. In order not to double the development time, use [Chaos Monkey](http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos).
21. Test your extension with cache `on` and cache `off`.
22. Avoid using uppercase letter in the module and class names. If not
     properly tested this may cause issues on different OS. This is more a recommendation, not a 'must'.
23. Dispatch events in your code to make it easier for developers to
     alter the functionality.
24. Follow the same coding standards that Magento uses and comment your code.
25. Do not use PHP short tags (`<? $this->doSomething() ?>`). Use full tags (`<?php $this->doSomething()?>`). Also don't use short echo tags, yet. (`<?="D'oh";?>`). Use (`<?php echo "D'oh";?>`)
26. Translate your texts using `$this->__` and add the locale translation file with your texts (`app/local/en_US/Easylife_Articles.csv`) at least for `en_US` language. Not all websites are built in English and the identification of texts to translate is time consuming.
27. If you sell an extension offer at least basic support. Or at least
     answer the support e-mails you receive.
28. **Do not make constant calls to your servers through your extension for licence validation. Once, at installation is more than enough (I don't like this approach either, but it's better than to make calls all the time).
     (Inspired by [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146))**
29. Develop with the log activated and from time to time take a look at
     the `var/log/system.log` file. The errors listed here are not shown
     even with developer mode on. If there is at least one error you end
     up with a large log file after a few months of running the extension.
30. If your extension affects the checkout process or the orders in
     some way, make sure it works with multi-shipping, or if it
     shouldn't work with multi-shipping, make sure it doesn't affect it.
31. **Do not replace the default Admin Notification bar (or feed URL). If
     I'm interested in what you have to offer I will subscribe to your
     newsletter. Let me see what Magento has to say. It's more important
     to me.**
32. **If you encrypt your code files with Ioncube (or something
     else)...well...I just hate you and I hope your business goes bankrupt**

That's what  have so far. I will add more as soon as I think of something else.

Comment: I agree with you, it's definitely a good start. For sure, you will also understand that it's not always possible to cover all different kind of configuration and issues, at least it will reduce the possible one. Most of problem I meet with other extensions or people meet with mine are due to conflict with overwriting.

Comment: @SylvainRayé. I agree. this will not cover all the possible issues, I also think that the answers to this question may be opinion based from one point forward, but I hope to build a list of common sense steps to follow to make developers lives easier. I also want to say that this question was asked out of rage, because I'm tired of paying for some extensions and spending time in fixing them. I could do something else in that time...like...nothing.

Comment: @Marius,sure 1+ from me.it covers most of the cases and scenario what we are facing in development.

Comment: Re #25: There is a difference between short tags (<?) and short echo tags (<?=). In PHP 5.4, the short echo tag is *always* enabled. In PHP 5.3 it is optional, but 5.3 has hit EOL and will only get bug fixes for another 9 months. PHP *is* a templating language after-all and IMO it is time we start using the short echo tag. :)

Comment: @ColinM. First of all it's an honor to have your comment here. :). I agree there is a difference, I will modify the answer, but I still think that both of them should be avoided, at least until PHP 5.3 becomes the "new PHP 4". I mean it is still used on a large scale.

Comment: @Marius Really impressed with your question/answer. Good Knowledge sharing!

Comment: super answer..keep it up!!

Comment: Perfect..+1 ..But you have missed one main thing..Testing modules in other Magento versions..

Comment: @Elavarasan. That's kind of a grey area. Usually when you sell/release an extension you specify the versions supported. But an extension can be valid even if it doesn't support all the versions. So if you state that an extensnion works on CE-1.7 then you are covered if it does not work on 1.8.

Comment: Okay.. But I thought it would be considerable ... And I always having requirement from my client, like "I want it will work on other (from 1.6) magento versions" ..So I will test that module in other (from 1.6) versions.. And also some modules in magento connect wont work in other versions even they mentioned compatibility. correct me If I wrong ..

Comment: @Elavarasan. I agree...there are a lot of shitty extensions on magento connect that don't even work on the specified versions, but that falls in the category "test your extension". See what DavidManners wrote in the other answer. I don't think it's mandatory to make an extension work in any version if you don't want to. It's a nice to have thing, but not mandatory. Then again, this is my opinion. Feel free to add an other answer with your additional steps.

Comment: @Marius, your points are very helpful. Till #31 I was seriously focusing on each point, but on #32 I just burst out a loud laugh. +1 specially for point #32

Comment: `If you encrypt your code files with Ioncube (or something else)...well...I just hate you and I hope your business goes bankrupt` I feel the same.

There are some companies that don't offer updated version, you will have to pay for them, it's really frustrating for me and don't understand why they want to sell same product again and again (to make money? obviously). I just don't buy their product anymore. You know whom I talking about.

Comment: I have read You answer carefully.. i am a new magento 2 Developer, You answer is based on Magento 1 standards is there any guide for better code quailty in magento 2

Comment: @WaqarAli most of the things listed above apply to magento 2 also. but there are other new ones. Best place would be the dev docs.

Comment: I have read this steps and it's really nice answer i have followed steps to create custom extensions.

Answer (score 33):

I am a big fan of using [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) so that I can develop and source control just my extension and leave the core files and folder structure unchanged. It is also makes testing across different installations run smoother.

Oh and one massive tip always try to install your packaged extension locally on a clean install of magento before uploading it to Magento Connect, I have missed out files so many times in the package manager.

Comment: Good call about the 'install your packaged extension locally'. I think this falls in the category: 'Test your god damn extension top to bottom'.

Comment: I've been caught out by this before too. Make sure you test the package on a clean install that is **not** the same one you packaged it on!

Answer (score 24):

Andreas von Studnitz and Dr. Nikolai Krambrock gave a good presentation on code quality on the Meet Magento DE 2014. They distinguish between general code quality and Magento-specific code quality. In short, there are the following general rules:

- The use of structure elements - just like classes and methods - should be arranged in middle seizes classes. These elements of the structure only make sense when they are used for structuring. Therefore they have to be of medium size. It is regarded to use 100-200 Lines of Code for classes and 3-20 Lines of Code for methods.
- Because of the use of "if" or "while" the code is indented. If there are more than 3 indentations it is better to revise them. Too many indentations are evidence for the code's complexity and should, therefore, be avoided.
- Dead Code should be avoided and deleted. Static analyses help to find it if one exists.

Even more important are the Magento-specific rules:

- Modules should work independently. They should only have little dependency on other modules and no dependency on templates. A solution is to use layout-updates (base/default) instead of adaption to template files and a module that covers additional functions of the template.
- To maintain the ability of updates in Magento core-hacks and hacks of external modules should be avoided. A better way is the use of rewriters or observer instead.
- For changes, it is better to use setup scripts instead of direct changes of the database or of the admin. Thanks to them changes have to be done only onetime.

Here are some more details and a video of the presentation:
http://www.code4business.de/code-quality-magento/

Comment: But If you had an english version of the link you posted would be even better.

Comment: An English version of this presentation is going to be written soon. I will keep you current and I will share the new link as soon as the English version is published.

Comment: An English version of the presentation is online now. Here is the link to it: http://www.code4business.de/code-quality-magento/

Comment: huh? It's still in German. But I just happened to attend this presentation in English at MeetMagentRo about 2 weeks ago. Great stuff.

Answer (score 19):

If you sell your extension or share it with others, think about writing code that is human readable.

1. don't make method too complex
2. add DOC blocks to your methods <sup>*****</sup>
3. use proper variable names, like `$productIds` instead of `$ids`
4. same for methods, `public function myOnProductSaveMethod() {...}` says ... nothing , but `tryDisableInternetOnProductSave()` will give a hint want's planned
5. use type hints where it makes sense `someMethod(Varien_Data_Db_Collection $collection)`
6. avoid [magic numbers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79490/mage-catalog-model-product-typetype-configurable-vs-configurable/79495#79495) and strings <sup>******</sup>
7. if you use models set `$_eventPrefix` property (and `$_eventObject`) to make them better accessible to observers
8. if you add system config fields

   - set default values in `config.xml`
   - add `<validate>` nodes to fields in `system.xml`
   - add ACL resources to `adminhtml.xml`
9. do not add useless/advertising first-level menu entries in admin backend - neither in topbar nor in config sections
10. add ACL resources for all controller actions (massactions too!)
11. ensure your queries work with DB [table prefixes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/167944/46249)
12. think about (no) backward comptibility *(this is really opinion based)*

    - do not support `Mysql4` classes
    - do not use deprecated methods
13. ensure your extionsion works as expected in every case - add UnitTests (PhpUnit for example)
14. in addition to [David Manners](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8361/46249) ... add a `composer.json` too to make deployment easier
15. since PHP5.6 is EOL, write your code for PHP7. Use `declare(strict_types=1);` and define your in- and output types
16. Magento2: check your code with static code analyze tools like [phpstan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan). Support for magic methods [here](https://github.com/fooman/phpstan-magento2-magic-methods). (latest commit works with 2.3, before for 2.1/2.2 - taht require phpstan 0.8.5)

---

<sup>* DOC blocks:</sup>

If you check your Magento-1 code with PHP_CodeSniffer for PSR2 standard or [PHPMD](https://phpmd.org/) you maybe want to add this lines (where it makes sense) ...

- to classes

  - `@phpcs:disable PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace`
  - `@phpcs:disable PSR2.Classes.PropertyDeclaration.Underscore` - inherited properties
  - `@phpcs:disable Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName.NotCamelCaps`
  - `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CamelCaseClassName)`
  - `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CamelCasePropertyName)` - inherited properties
- to methods

  - `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CamelCaseMethodName)` - inherited methods
  - `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.StaticAccess)` - if you use `Mage::` or other static calls

<sup>** Often used:</sup>

- admin store ID

  - `0` > `Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID`
- product `status`

  - `1` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED`
  - `2` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED` *(not `0` as maybe expected)*
- product `type`

  - `simple` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE`
  - `bundle` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE`
  - `configurable` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE`
  - `grouped` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED`
  - `virtual` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL`
- product `visibity`

  - `1` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE`
  - `2` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG`
  - `3` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH`
  - `4` > `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH`

Same for SQL order `ASC` vs `Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC` *(for example)*.

Saying *"it's not nessessary cause it will never ever change"*? For example entity ID for `catalog_product` attributes changed somewhere between Magento 1.5 and 1.9 from `10` to `4`, so this could break your extension:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', 10)
```

Using this instead adds one query, but you'll be safe ...

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
    ->getEntityTypeId();

$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityTypeId)
```

Answer (score 9):

@marius, regarding Coding Standards (point 24 in your list).

I like to use [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) along with [EQP](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp) **and** [ECG](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard) CS to automatically enforce these standards.

Using [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) you don't have to worry about forgetting things like replacing `array()` with `[]`, avoid using `is_null`, leave unused local variables or even a method without PHPDoc block.

[PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) will always tell you about it.

Comment: Agreed! Possible howto: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178640/ecg-compliance-how-to-do

Comment: I think there is no way to configure both CS in PHPStorm (for those who use PHPStorm) but you can always use the terminal to check the CS in your code. Also there are tools such as grumphp https://github.com/phpro/grumphp that help a bit.

Comment: It might be help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch?noredirect=1#comment277175_200022