# Create extension - create translate file?

Tags: extensions

I am creating an extension with an admin page and I will put it magento connect. 
I put all texts in __('text...') ?>, but I don't need to translate them.

So do you think I have to add informations for translations in my config.xml file, even if I don't create a [my_module].csv file ?

```
<translate>
    <modules>
       <[my_module]>
           <files>
               <default>[my_module].csv</default>
          </files>
      </[my_module]>
     </modules>
< /translate>
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

The extension works even if you don't have and don't declare a translation file.
But in order to make your extension easier to translate, you should put all your texts in a `[Namespace]_[Module].csv` translation file at least for the English version.
This way, if I want to use your extension on a website (let's say) in Romanian all I have to do is to copy your `[Namespace]_[Module].csv` file from `en_US` to `ro_RO` and translate the texts.
Read more guidelines about [How to write a custom extension?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8344/146) (point 26 is related to translations)
I know that collecting texts from your module can be a bit of a "monkey job", time consuming and not very challenging, but you should do it.
I can even give you a monkey to do it. take a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool). You just need to fill in the files and folders of your module and it will collect the translatable texts in one file. Then just put that file in `app/locale/en_US`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to add a translate .CSV file if you're not going to add one to your module.