# Custom module, controller action trigger

Tags: module, magento-1, action

I am developer, new to magento, and I just took over a project from another dev team so the code is totally strange to me. 
They built a custom module, and I have trouble figuring out when/where a certain action from inside a controller is triggered.

Here is the file structure/path:
app -> code -> local -> FOLDER -> MODULE FOLDER -> controllers -> IndexController.php
Inside this index controller lies the **indexAction()** action.

When is this action triggered?
What should I look for?
Any idea is helpful

Comment: I think you'll need to read through this:http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension should give you a complete understanding.

Answer (score 2):

After you enable the module, there is config.xml file for each module(which is at NAMESPACE/MODULENAME/etc/config.xml), there should be something like this:

```
<config>  
....

<frontend>
        <routers>
            <MODULENAME>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NAMESPACE_MODULENAME</module>
                    <frontName>path</frontName>
                </args>
            </MODULENAME>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>

...
</config>
```

According to your, Question you can reach controllers with following url:
`http://DOMAIN_NAME/path/index/index`
Here the **path** is from config.xml's , first **index** is IndexController and second **index**  is method(action) indexAction() in IndexController.

P.S:  `-> FOLDER -> MODULE FOLDER ==> NAMESPACE -> MODULENAME`

Comment: and if I wanted to do a php redirect to that indexAction(), how would that look like?

Comment: if you want to redirect from another controller to indexAction() then use:
$this->_redirect('path/index/index');
from other
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("path/index/index"))

Comment: did it solve your problem? if so please mark as if so please mark as solved.