# Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_TYPE::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE vs 'configurable'

Tags: magento-1.7, fatal-error, best-practice, product-type, coding-standards

I'm working on an heavy customised magento version. Cancelling an order returned this fatal error:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_TYPE not found
```

on this line code:

```
if($parent->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_TYPE::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
```

I fixed changing it to

```
if($parent->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
```

Can you please tell me what's the difference between them and if my solution can lead to other issues?
many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE` (notice the capitalization, which was the source of your error) is a **constant**. Using a constant for values that won't change is preferred over writing "magic strings"<sup>1</sup> all over the application.

### Why?

- no errors due to typos. If you misspell the string, chances are, you won't notice until much later. If you reference a non existent constant, the compiler complains immediately (or with PHP, your IDE or static code analysis tools like CodeSniffer)
- easier to refactor
- more context, thus easier to understand. It is clear, where the value comes from and what purpose it serves

---

<sup>1) Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad - it is about magic numbers, but magic strings are almost as bad</sup>

Answer (score 5):

It should be `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type` and not `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_TYPE` (note the capitalisation on the last word)

Comment: thanks, did't see the difference. but what about my solution?

Comment: Your solution would work but is much less elegant as you hard-code values.