# Magento customer reset password customer_flowpassword error

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, password, bug, magento-1.9.3.2

I currently have a error in my 1.9.3.2 store.

When a customer wants to reset their password, the Magento Report error page is displayed.

When check the report, I get the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:156:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'customer_flowpassword' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `customer_flowpassword`";i:1;s:2832:"#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Problem is related to the update to 1.9.3.2, where the table was not created.

Should this solve the issue?

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_flowpassword` (
  `flowpassword_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Flow password Id',
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User IP',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested email for change',
  `requested_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Requested date for change',
  PRIMARY KEY (`flowpassword_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_EMAIL` (`email`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_IP` (`ip`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_REQUESTED_DATE` (`requested_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer flow password' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: The table `customer_flowpassword` is not available, check which module is using the table and try to run the setup script for that module

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with 1.9.3. That should create that table. See my update. Do you know how to run this?

Comment: Please add your config file code for the same module and name of your SQL file which has table creation code

Comment: @John What exactly do you mean? By updating from 1.9.3.1 to 1.9.3.2 this table should be created by Magento, but that did not happen. So how can I solve this?

Comment: If you can add your config.xml file and your setup script name, I will guide you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Go to database table `core_resource`, Find an entry for your module- could be `customer_flowpassword_setup` - and delete it.
Now refresh any page on your magento setup. It should re-run your setup script and will create table. Don't forget to refresh your cache.

**Solution 2**

Directly run below SQL in your database.

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_flowpassword` (
  `flowpassword_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Flow password Id',
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User IP',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested email for change',
  `requested_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Requested date for change',
  PRIMARY KEY (`flowpassword_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_EMAIL` (`email`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_IP` (`ip`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_REQUESTED_DATE` (`requested_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer flow password' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Answer (score 8):

This **is** a bug in Magento core, not recognizing your "table prefix" (confimed [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/162))

See: `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Observer.php`

Original code doesn't check for prefix ...

```
public function deleteCustomerFlowPassword()
{
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('write');
    $condition  = array('requested_date < ?' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date(null, '-1 day'));
    $connection->delete($connection->getTableName('customer_flowpassword'), $condition);
}
```

It should look like ...

```
public function deleteCustomerFlowPassword()
{
    $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('write');
    $condition  = array('requested_date < ?' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date(null, '-1 day'));
    $connection->delete($resource->getTableName('customer_flowpassword'), $condition);
}
```

Comment: I get really narky at Magento extension developers when they make that mistake, but in the core? Muppets!

Comment: Is this already fixed? We have 2019 now

Comment: @Black still present in 1.9.4.1 ...