# Add an external js file with custom name using integration

Tags: magento2, javascript, integration

Is it possible to add an external js file based on domain name from integration ?

Lets say the domain is: example.com. When user installs my integration, I want to add a myintegration.com/examplecom.js to my magento store.

Comment: may be this can help you [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="http://myintegration.com/examplecom.js" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I don't have a default.xml and the script name should be generated with php depending on the domain name. I can't use php in xml.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but I think you can do this with require. 
In the `requirejs-config.js` of your module you can do something like:

```
var domain = window.location.hostname,  
    jsPath = 'myintegration.com/' + domain.match(/(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\//) + '.js';

var config = {
    "paths": {
            "myintegration": jsPath
    }
};
```

(Indicative code, not tested)