# How to create custom Module Development in magento 2 from Scratch?

Tags: magento2, grid, crontab, cli, webapi

How to create Custom Module Development from scratch in magento 2 with following point.

1.How to Create Module

2.How to Install and Upgrade Database

3.How to Create Module,view and Controller Layers

4.How to Test Integration of all module components

6.How to create  Magento CLI command

7.How to Configure scheduled task in Magento 2

8.How to create  Menu entry

9.How to Create ACL resource

10. How to Implement web API in Magento with custom table

11.How to create Custom Grid In admin

12. How to create Form Using UI component and save and redirect to Grid

I would like to share source code with all guys

Comment: What is your question? What's problem?

Comment: @SohelRana Sir, I am new to magento 2. basically new candidates get number of problem while custom Module Development so I thought to share my source code which will help to someone. if you have any suggestion for me please, let me know.

Comment: @PramodKharade in order to improve the clarity of your question and receive a greater reputation on this stack, it may be worth asking and answering each of these points as separate questions. Your answer is exactly what I've been looking for in order to solve a lot of problems, but it's quite difficult to find using the stackexchange search engine.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood thanks . next time i will bring up with new concept with separate question and ans. Please vote for ans so it will help to other reader .

Comment: I am getting the 404, any other step need to do?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140185)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140185)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Namespace: Mastering\Itdesire

1.How to Create Module

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Mastering_Itdesire" setup_version="1.0.1">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/registration.php

```
    <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Mastering_Itdesire',
        __DIR__
    );
```

2.How to Install and Upgrade Database :

Install Schema :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of InstallSchema
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Item ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Item Name'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName('mastering_itdesire_item', ['name']),
            ['name']
        )->setComment(
            'itdesire Items'
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Install Data :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of InstallData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 1'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 2'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Upgrade Schema :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of UpgradeSchema
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
                'description',
                [
                    'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Item Description'
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Upgrade Data :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of UpgradeData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->update(
                $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
                [
                    'description' => 'Default description'
                ],
                $setup->getConnection()->quoteInto('id = ?', 1)
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

3.How to Create Model,view and Controller Layers

Controller :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Index
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Index extends Action{
    //put your code here
    public function execute() {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $result->setContents('Hello Admins!');
        return $result;
    }

}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Index
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
class Index extends Action{
    //put your code here
    public function execute() {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $result */
        /*
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $result->setContents('Hello World!');
        return $result; */
      return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }

}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mastering" frontName="mastering">
            <module name="Mastering_Itdesire"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/frontend/layout/mastering_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="mastering_hello" class="Mastering\Itdesire\Block\Hello" template="hello.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Model, Resource Model and API :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Collection
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\Item;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item as ItemResource;
class Collection extends AbstractCollection {
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Item::class, ItemResource::class);
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/ResourceModel/Item.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Item
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Item extends AbstractDb {
   protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mastering_itdesire_item', 'id');
    }

}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * Description of Config
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
class Config {
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'mastering/general/enabled';

    private $config;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->config->getValue(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED);
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/Item.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Item
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Item extends AbstractModel{
    //put your code here
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init(\Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item::class);
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/ItemRepository.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model;

/**
 * Description of ItemRepository
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
use Mastering\Itdesire\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
class ItemRepository implements ItemRepositoryInterface {
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getList() {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    }

}
```

View :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Block/Hello.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Hello
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
class Hello extends Template{
    //put your code here
    private $collectionFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context,
            CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            array $data = array()) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

   /**
     * @return \Mastering\Itdesire\Model\Item[]
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/frontend/templates/hello.phtml

```
<?php 
/***
 * @var \Mastering\Itdesire\Block\Hello $block
 * ***/

?>
<?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item){

    ?>
<p>
    <?php echo $item->getName();?>: <?php echo $item->getDescription();?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

4.How to create Magento CLI command :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Console/Command/AddItem.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of AddItem
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ItemFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;

class AddItem extends Command{

    const INPUT_KEY_NAME ="name";
    const INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION ="description";
    private $itemFactory;

    public function __construct(ItemFactory $itemFactory) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure() {
        $this->setName("itdesire:item:add")
                ->addArgument(
                               self::INPUT_KEY_NAME,
                               InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                               'Input Name'
                             )->addArgument(
                                     self::INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                                     InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                                     "Input Description"
                            );
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $item = $this->itemFactory->create();
        $item->setName($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_NAME));
        $item->setDescription($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        $item->setIsObjectNew(true);
        $item->save();
        return Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

5.How to Configure scheduled task in Magento 2 :

> Mastering/Itdesire/Cron/AddItem.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of addItem
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Cron;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ItemFactory;
use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\Config;
class AddItem {
    private $itemFactory;
    private  $config;
    public function __construct(ItemFactory $itemFactory,Config $config) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->config->isEnabled()){
            $this->itemFactory->create()
            ->setName('Scheduled item')
            ->setDescription('Created at ' . time())
            ->save();
        }

    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <mastering>
            <general>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <cron_expression>* * * * *</cron_expression>
            </general>
        </mastering>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="masteringAddItem" instance="Mastering\Itdesire\Cron\AddItem" method="execute">
            <config_path>mastering/general/cron_expression</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="mastering" translate="label" sortOrder="10000">
            <label>Mastering</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mastering" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Mastering</label>
            <tab>mastering</tab>
            <resource>Mastering_Itdesire::mastering</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Item creation by schedule</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="cron_expression" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Add Item Cron Expression</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

6.How to create Menu entry :

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
        <menu>
            <add id="Mastering_Itdesire::mastering" title="Mastering"
                 module="Mastering_Itdesire" resource="Mastering_Itdesire::mastering"
                 translate="title" sortOrder="900" action="mastering"/>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

7.How to Create ACL resource :

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Masteting_Itdesire::mastering" title="Mastering"
                          translate="title" sortOrder="900"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

8.How to Implement web API in Magento with custom table :

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="masteringAddItem" xsi:type="object">Mastering\Itdesire\Console\Command\AddItem</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference type="Mastering\Itdesire\Model\Item" for="Mastering\Itdesire\Api\Data\ItemInterface"/>
    <preference type="Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ItemRepository" for="Mastering\Itdesire\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface"/>
</config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes>
    <route url="/V1/mastering" method="GET">
        <service class="Mastering\Itdesire\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can get all source code here also: https://github.com/pramodkharade/Magento2

Comment: Hello @Pramod :). Excellent answer! I'm still a bit confused though about my particular problem. Would I need to implement this same solution if my aim were to assign a discount code to a different, random product each week? Or would I be able to store and retrieve data about that week's product without using an API?

My question is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212734/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-variable-for-use-within-a-custom-module

Thanks again!

Comment: @PramodKharade ItemFactory does not exist in model

Comment: When i ran upgrade command got the error [ReflectionException]                                       
  Class Mastering\Itdesire\Console\Command\AddItem does not exist @PramodKharade

Comment: but you haven't explained the working of code :(

Comment: bookmarked the page. :)

Answer (score 5):

**11.Custom Grid In admin as continued here exceeding length of file in above ans**:

> Mastering/Itdesire/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="masteringAddItem" xsi:type="object">Mastering\Itdesire\Console\Command\AddItem</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference type="Mastering\Itdesire\Model\Item" for="Mastering\Itdesire\Api\Data\ItemInterface"/>
    <preference type="Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ItemRepository" for="Mastering\Itdesire\Api\ItemRepositoryInterface"/>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="mastering_item_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mastering_item_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_grid.mastering_item_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_grid.mastering_item_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Item</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/item/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="mastering_item_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <frontendLink name="frontend_link"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="mastering_item_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_grid.mastering_item_grid.mastering_item_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/adminhtml/layout/mastering_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="mastering_item_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Collection
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Grid;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'mastering_itdesire_item',
        $resourceModel = 'Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item'
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $mainTable,
            $resourceModel
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

**12.How to create Form Using UI component and save and redirect to Grid**

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/adminhtml/layout/mastering_item_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="admin-2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="mastering_item_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mastering_item_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form.mastering_item_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form.mastering_item_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
            <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="mastering_item_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Mastering\Itdesire\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="collectionFactory" xsi:type="object">Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="mastering/item/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Ui/DataProvider.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of DataProvider
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Ui;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $collection;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($this->collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $result[$item->getId()]['general'] = $item->getData();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Controller/Adminhtml/Item/NewAction.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of NewAction
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Controller\Adminhtml\Item;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class NewAction extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }
}
```

> Mastering/Itdesire/Controller/Adminhtml/Item/Save.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Save
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Controller\Adminhtml\Item;

use Mastering\Itdesire\Model\ItemFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Save extends Action
{
    private $itemFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        ItemFactory $itemFactory
    ) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->itemFactory->create()
            ->setData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue()['general'])
            ->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('mastering/index/index');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pramod Kharade :). Just noticed that your first answer goes up to step 8. but this answer continues at step 11. Are you missing steps or was there a typo?

Comment: Hi how can I add edit and delete action in grid column?

Comment: Yes , we can add it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice blog to solve answer your question : https://learn2code2web.com/2020/12/14/magento-2-custom-module-development/