# How to save backend form data in database in magento 2

Tags: php, grid, backend, magento2.2

I have created an admin grid and also created an associated form for that grid. And then I have created a table for that grid. Now, how to save the form data that particular grid DB table

Comment: Here you can get CURD operations. Hope it may help you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch/200204#200204

Comment: Thank you. I have created Model file. But I need to save data in data base. Please suggest me how to modify the above code

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a model corresponding to the table, from which you will be able to do all db related stuff.
Following is a good tutorial on how to make model ;
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller into adminhtml folder and create one model to get table in which you want to save that data Create model factory in your controller and get form data over there using post method and set that data in controller