# Cannot add new cli command "Class does not exist" on setup:upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1, module, command

I am trying add custom command for beginning 'hello world'. I'm doing all by guide but always have this error

> [ReflectionException]
>     Class Hesoy\HelloWorld\Console\Command\HelloWorldCommand does not exist

This is my setup steps:

1. Clear cache
2. setup:upgrade

This is my files

Command

```
namespace Hesoy\HelloWorld\Console\Command;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HelloWorldCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('hesoy:hello-world')
            ->setDescription('Hello world');

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Hello world!');
    }
}
```

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="helloWorld" xsi:type="object">Hesoy\HelloWorld\Console\Command\HelloWorldCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Hesoy_HelloWorld" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module>
</config
```

registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Hesoy_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: refer this post where you can get an idea to create new command:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So idiot mistake, it was wrong module [VendorName]/[ModuleName].
Was `app/code/hesoy/hello-world` and need `app/code/Hesoy/HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid di.xml. Please correct it.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="helloWorld" xsi:type="object">Hesoy\HelloWorld\Console\Command\HelloWorldCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is my typo. Edited question.