# Magento 2 : How to write a custom extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions, best-practice, coding-standards, documentation

There is already a question on how to write a custom extension at [How to write a custom extension?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension) , but most of the answers I read , while being good and really detailed are about magento 1, so felt the need to ask it again.

Comment: Here you can find custom module Development: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch?noredirect=1#comment277175_200022

Answer (score 2):

I believe that official documentation has a pretty good answer to this question. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you can refer this link ,which is pretty good solution for understanding for magento 2 development :
[M2 Custom Extention](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/)