# Magento 2. Command that is executed when admin:user:create is executed

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2, command

Magento 2 has a console command `admin:user:create`

At a quick search we find a class that defines a command with such a name  `Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand`

Yet putting a `breakpoint` or even the old `var_dump die` seems to have no effect when this console command is run `admin:user:create`.

So what code is executed when we run `admin:user:create` from the console?

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        var_dump("here");
        exit;
        $errors = $this->validate($input);
        if ($errors) {
            $output->writeln('<error>' . implode('</error>' . PHP_EOL . '<error>', $errors) . '</error>');
            // we must have an exit code higher than zero to indicate something was wrong
            return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE;
        }
        $installer = $this->installerFactory->create(new ConsoleLogger($output));
        $installer->installAdminUser($input->getOptions());
        $output->writeln(
            '<info>Created Magento administrator user named ' . $input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_USER) . '</info>'
        );
    }
```

Does nothing. The command executes freely.

Comment: It may help you.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch

Comment: It does not. But that is a great post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classes `Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand`. 
One is placed inside `setup` dir and the other one is inside `vendor/magento2-base`.

Magento usses the one from `root/setup/src/Magento/Setup..`.

The `interact` method always executes first. Followed by the `execute` method.