# How to get data from custom table and display it in page in Admin Panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, database, cms-pages, magento2.2.3

I am new to Magento. My Magento version is 2.2.3

I have created the page as explained here [Magento tutroial](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/page-add.html). Now I want to get the custom table data from database and show it in html table in the same page. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create resourcemodel and model for custom table. Refer this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch