# Form is not executed in admin panel form url show too many redirects error i give link in body

Tags: uicomponent, ui-form, ui-grid

[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch) form is not visible and give too many redirects error

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably being caused because the admin portal is attempting to get the javascript and css files via normal http, as opposed to https.

To correct this, try to set Use Secure URLs in Admin to true, in `System -> Config -> General -> Web`.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: where i get this config file in system the config file is not available

Comment: In Magento Admin  in System -> Config -> General -> Web > Use Secure URLs

Comment: hamerdra sir it's not working after changing url it give error for admin dashboard also

Comment: ok, Try this -  In the "core_config_data" table remove the value of "web/cookie/cookie_domain" and set "web/cookie/cookie_httponly" to "0". Clear the cache by removing the files in "var/cache" & check.

Comment: how i remove the var/cache files?

Comment: In magento root folder, there will be "var" named folder in that directory "cache" folder/file exist. delete those cache files. OR use this command php bin/magento c:c

Comment: can tell me the url for run the form when i hit  the localhost/magento2/admin/mastering  then it show the (hello admins )output not the form

Comment: yes because controller returns "hello admin" in Mastering/Itdesire/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php file. If form not appearing You can check the errors for var/log and var/reports folder

Comment: Set developer mode php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer to see the errors directly.

Comment: can you tell me how i pass the form link instead of hello admin page

Comment: That is already answered here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch

Comment: can you check the code the link and the colmuns for table are connected or not with the Form and what url i use for show that form?

Comment: Your url is localhost/magento2/admin/mastering. One question, have you created Mastering/Itdesire/etc/di.xml file ?

Comment: yes sir i created di.xml file i pastes same all above code that given in link

Comment: There must be something missing, probably issue is with file name. Recheck the same steps, file name & contents. You can also refer the github code for that module -https://github.com/pramodkharade/Magento2/tree/master/app/code/Mastering (Source -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch)

Comment: can you expalin the files which file for which work we used

Comment: You can check tutorials for magento. That explains better.