# How to Create a field in the UiForm in which the csv file can be uploaded and read on the submit to store its fields in database in magento2?

Tags: magento2, csv, ui-form

How to Create a field in the *UiForm*  in **admin panel** in which the csv file can be uploaded and read on the submit to store its fields in database  in magento2?

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean by "Admin panel" is that a custom form or a system config?

Comment: custom form in admin panel  the form link is https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200022/how-to-create-custom-module-development-in-magento-2-from-scratch) now i want add the one more field for taking csv file as a input in this code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the: "FileUploader component"(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html)

In the path="path/to/controller", he will fire an event once you've chosen your file,
my suggestion is to upload the file initially in a specific folder, and then on the submit, check for the file existence and reading it doing your logic.(All of this if that's a ui-component form )